# Suppes Axiomatic Set Theory Ch.1 Exercise 1

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification, proof-writing

I'm trying to prove the following theorem from Suppes,

**Theorem**

$$A\subset B\implies\lnot(B\subset A).$$

Here's the definition I used in my proof:

**Definition**

$$A\subset B\implies A\subseteq B\land A\neq B.$$

Finally this is my proof:

*proof.*

Suppose $A\subset B$. Then by **Definition** we have
\begin{align*}
            A\subset B\implies A\subseteq B\land A\neq B.
        \end{align*}
But, $A\subseteq B\land A\neq B\implies(\exists x)(x\in B\land x\notin A)$, i.e., $x\in B$ does not imply that $x\in A$. Therefore $\lnot(B\subset A)$.

Is this correct?

Comment: Looks good to me.

Comment: Fine. Good job of using definitions. Nothing works without the using of def'ns. Note that many other authors use $A\subset B$ to mean the same thing as $A\subseteqq B$ and use $A\subsetneqq B$ when necessary.